# how to make own custom widgets like facebook social plugins?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, html

How do I make my own widget just like facebook? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins

Basically it's a bit of javascript, css and html code, but how to do it?
Any example, tutorials?

Comment: Do you mean how do you serve html via javascript? Same way you would locally.

Comment: Just code your widget like you would normally (using HTML, CSS and JS), then either use an `iframe` to embed it on other pages or use JS to fetch the data with ajax and append `style` and `script` elements your widget needs  to the page using the widget.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend [Third Party Javascript (Manning)](http://www.manning.com/vinegar/) from the guys at Disqus for a great overview of everything. While it won't give you a magic bullet solution for your SDK/widget-making, it will help you bullet-proof things as you go. It's a great reference, if short/concise and the code is definitely not for JavaScript beginners.

As to how Facebook does it, while it's not fully descriptive of their iframe/widget approach, it shows how they do bullet-proof embedding in non-standard webpages: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/the-art-and-craft-of-the-async-snippet/

For extra bonus points, combine that with http://www.phpied.com/non-onload-blocking-async-js/ and it should get rid of the loading spinner in all but iOS 6 if memory serves me well.

For even more advanced iframe fun, see https://github.com/benvinegar/seamless-talk and any other slides/posts at http://benv.ca/. (I think I'd like to meet Ben one day, given how much of his stuff I've been borrowing from lately, and he's a fellow Canadian to boot.)

Note that seamless iframes, as a native browser concept, are webkit-only and buggy at that: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99289 (On Firefox, dev. is stopped due to an 11-year old bug? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631218) So for the foreseeable future, iframe customization will require JavaScript. :)

Comment: I could also note that in the future, I suspect we will all be using HTML5 Web Components for this sort of thing, though for now native implementations are far and few between. I've been looking enviously at dart's web_ui lately, though...

Comment: The links you posted have really helped me, have you got any more?

Comment: @marflar I can follow up by saying "easyXDM" makes postMessage-style iframe-to-parent communication possible in IE6-7 with Flash, but if you can help it, try to design your widget to gracefully fallback to static iframe content instead as easyXDM is too expensive (in bits) to load. For real isolation + speed, consider an src-less iframe in the parent that loads and manages all widget operations across "view"-like iframes embedded on your page (like G+), and if possible try a modern JS framework like Angular.js.

Answer (score 4):

Look here for a tutorial on how to build your own widget using JSONP:

http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

and here on how to make it secure:

http://wordpress.tv/2011/08/31/mike-adams-developing-secure-widgets-secure-iframe-communication-in-a-pre-postmessage-world/

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the Facebook Javascript SDK (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). You need to understand the Graph API (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) which you can query from the Javascript SDK.  Throughout Facebook's documentation there's tonnes of example code.  Have fun!

Comment: hi, DMCS i dont mean how to use facebook widgets but create my own custom widget like facebook has done it :)

Comment: Yes, those links will get you there.  Happy coding!

Comment: That will create a facebook widget, i want to create my own widget not a facebook widget.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't understand your question originally.  Can you clarify what you're wanting to do?

Comment: I want to make my own custom widget so other developers can use content from my site on their site.

Comment: Ok, so you don't need any content from Facebook, which means you don't need their APIs.  Just content from one web site to another web site.  That's fairly easy to accomplish using web services in a SOA, where the subscribing site calls the hosting site for content. Or even serve up the content using RSS.